# &nbsp; and <td> on PHP email issue

Tags: php, html-email

> `I'm using &nbsp; but getting � on my email. How can I fix this?`

Some part of the code:

```
    $review = "
        <table width='100%' border='0'>
        <tr>
            <td class='text_font' >Customer Name:&nbsp;&nbsp; $account_nam</td>
        </tr>
        </table>";
```

It displays as

Customer Name:�� Sample Account Name

Also this one:

> `<td width='20%' style='border-bottom: 1px solid #CECECE;'></td>`

`<td>` has no value but it display the funny symbol �

Comment: `htmlentities` or an encoding issue.

Comment: Not much bearing on the questions, but `width` and `border` attributes are a clunky no-no. Put that in the CSS, and even better put the css in a `<style>` block, and better than *that* is using a separate CSS file.

Comment: @Sammitch `width` and `border` are best practice for html-email

Comment: @Sammitch HTML email is like going 10 years back in HTML. Use as many inline style attributes as you can, as many `font` tags, as many `table`'s as you want, as the simpler the HTML (no matter how correct or wrong) the more likely it is to render correctly in all browsers.

Comment: Seperate CSS does not work in Outlook and most other Mail clients.

Comment: Did you tried meta tag ? (cf http://www.htmldog.com/guides/html/intermediate/metatags/)

Comment: @h2ooooooo http://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/ check the box model section.

Comment: @Sammitch width may be supported generally, but it is not as consistent as `width=""` when using table elements. If you don't believe it, ask anyone on the CM forum and they will say the same thing. Using a separate CSS file is also very much not applicable for html email.

Answer (score 1):

I guess that your encoding is UTF-8 and in the Mail client its ISO or vice versa.
Be sure to send the correct encoding in the mail header.

Producing a margin with blankspaces is anyways not a good idea, why not seperate table cells for field and value:

```
$review = "
    <table width='100%' border='0'>
    <tr>
        <td class='text_font' >Customer Name:</td>
        <td>" . $account_name . "</td>
    </tr>
    </table>";
```

Answer (score 0):

It is most likely an encoding issue. Possibly the setting on the editor you are using is saving the text in some encoding that is not recognized. I have had similar issues using notepad++ and not thinking about encoding.

Answer (score 0):

Chances are you have imported your text from MS word. Word has a few funky characters such as angled quotation marks etc.

You can use `htmlentities` as Daryl suggests in the comments, but I've found in the past that you have to str_replace those characters out like so:

```
$text = str_replace("&ldquo;", '"', $text);
$text = str_replace("&rdquo;", '"', $text);
$text = str_replace("&lsquo;", "'", $text);
$text = str_replace("&rsquo;", "'", $text);
$text = str_replace("&hellip;", '...', $text);
$text = str_replace("&ndash;", '-', $text);
```